# Build a production pedometer (step counter) app React Native

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, pedometer

Im building an app that tracks user steps in React Native.
Currently its impossible to use Expo (above 33) for the task, even when they dont mention it in their docs.

My other best course of action, will be to use Google fit Api & Apple Health services.

Im thinking on how to implement it without letting the user connect through his gmail (there is already a login to the app).

I was thinking about:
Sending every auth request to the server where it will be logged through a global google account for everyone, and it will do the request for the step calculation, and then will return it to the user. So the user doesnt really need to login through Google (not all users of a google account)

**The problem is that there is a query limitation of 300** a minute per user, and its a big user base, so I will max it out very quickly

Am I thinking about it right?
Or there is a way to get the steps through the client, without the need to query GoogleFit?

Do Google even allowing to use a "global" account for all users served by my app?

Thanks for replying.

Comment: is there a way to batch the data into a single request?

Comment: no really, cause evert user can ask to get the "currentStepCount" when ever they want.
It also means it will query GoogleFit from the same account but in different location around the country.